Dynamic nature of equilibrium - Justification (Is my idea correct ?)
My reasoning for the dynamic nature of equilibrium:

Equilibrium is dynamic in nature, at equilibrium the system has higher entropy, if the system can't find an even higher entropy, then it would want to stay at this state, but practically molecules move, changes occur, it is not possible to stop the motion of molecules, as a consequence, reverse reaction occurs this reverses the effects of the previous process, so in the forward and reversing process entropy is being averaged between these processes

I don't know if I am correct. If wrong or missing something please tell me.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
